# Searching for filenames containing specific word

Tags: command-line, files, search, find

How do i search for filenames containing a word (or multiple words), starting from some directory (not case sensitive) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The following command should work, where you have permissions

  ```
  find /start-directory -name "*word*"
  ```

  where you replace `/start-directory` with *your* particular directory path.
- in the current directory with

  ```
  find . -name "*word*"
  ```
- and the following command should work, where you need elevated permissions, for example to search the whole computer (via the root directory **`/`**

  ```
  sudo find / -name "*word*"
  ```

Comment: You seem to be missing a `find` in the last example - also the OP specified case-insensitivity (`-iname` rather than `-name`) and multiple search terms (e.g.  `-iname '*foo*' -iname '*bar*'`)